# Send event from php controller

Tags: php, websocket, yii2

Good morning everyone.
I need to send a notification whenever a user swipes a tab on a particular sensor.
The problem is not the connection to the sensor, which at this moment already takes place and subject to user access.
Currently I have created a server socket inside my yii2 app to be able to send the notification event to the client and update them in real time.

This is my controller server

```
class ServerController extends Controller
{
    public function actionStart()
    {
        // $server = new CommandsServer();
        $server = new ChatServer();
        $server->port = 80; //This port must be busy by WebServer and we handle an error

        $server->on(WebSocketServer::EVENT_WEBSOCKET_OPEN_ERROR, function ($e) use ($server) {
            echo "Error opening port " . $server->port . "\n";
            $server->port += 1; //Try next port to open
            $server->start();
        });

        $server->on(WebSocketServer::EVENT_WEBSOCKET_OPEN, function ($e) use ($server) {
            echo "Server started at port " . $server->port;
        });

        $server->start();
    }
}
```

This is my chat server which I created for testing

```
<?php

namespace frontend\daemons;

use consik\yii2websocket\events\WSClientEvent;
use consik\yii2websocket\WebSocketServer;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;



   

 class ChatServer extends WebSocketServer
{

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->on(self::EVENT_CLIENT_CONNECTED, function (WSClientEvent $e) {
            $e->client->name = null;
        });
    }


    protected function getCommand(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg)
    {
        $request = json_decode($msg, true);
        return !empty($request['action']) ? $request['action'] : parent::getCommand($from, $msg);
    }


   public function commandPing(ConnectionInterface $client, $msg)
    {
        $arr = ["Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank"];
        $res = ['type' => 'ping', 'message' => json_encode(array_rand($arr, 1))];
        foreach ($this->clients as $chatClient) {
            $chatClient->send(json_encode($res));
        }
    }
}
```

Now, what I wish I could do is be able to use that `commandPing` inside another controller, but I haven't found a way I can implement this.

In this sense the round would be:
user swipes card on sensor -> the sensor calls my method to see if the user is actually authorized to enter -> I call commandPing (as an example) to send a notification to the customer (OK / KO )

On the web interface side I will then intercept the message via new Websocket (but this is not a problem)

Comment: Sounds like you want your php code to connect to the chat server and send a message? If so, there are php libraries which allow you to act as a websocket client and send messages to such a server via a socket connection

Comment: In practice yes. I would like my current controller to keep doing its thing, plus it will send an event to my server socket which will in turn send to the frontend of the client which will show the message/popup, etc.
Can you suggest me something?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should just be able to google "php websocket client"